# Увеличение значений всего столбца БД

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, telebot

Я хочу сделать в боте функцию, которая будет ежедневно увеличивать значение столбца в БД на 1.

```
sql = "SELECT points FROM table"
cur.execute(sql)
old = cur.fetchall()
new = ()
for i in range(len(old)):
    new += (int(old[i][0]) + 1,)
```

Вот таким образом я получаю массив кортежей со всеми значениями столбца и создаю кортеж с новыми значениями

Но я не понимаю, как мне заменить старые значения одним запросом, так как

```
sql = """
    UPDATE table
    SET points = ?
    """
cur.execute(sql, new)
```

данный код не работает, потому что запрос хочет заменить все значения на одно.
Как надо составлять запрос для замены всего столбца?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"""
UPDATE table
SET points = points + 1
"""
```